# TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: calibri

Tags: tcpdf, html2pdf

When I try to use html2pdf I got an error: `"TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: calibri"`...

How to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

calibri is not a default font in tcpdf , you need to add it if you are going to use it in your file : check this https://tcpdf.org/docs/fonts/ . A liste of default fonts in tcpdf and how to add one.